# Facebook graph API post multiple Photos to album and feed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I have an iOS app that is posting multiple photos to facebook feed using graph api.

I have accomplished this by posting to graph path "me/photos". This puts the photos in the default App Album and shows it on the user feed.  Exactly as I want.

The problem is if I create a second (or multiple) posts, it merges the second post and subsequent posts with the first post and shows it at top of the feed.  So If I make X posts, there is only 1 entry in the feed and all images from the posts are posted to the album.

Whereas I want to be able to make multiple posts and have them show as separate posts on the feed.

Here's the high level code for one post:

```
while (key = [k nextObject]) {
    item = [self.selectedItemsDict objectForKey:key];
    url = [item objectForKey:kPicURLKey];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   url, @"url", nil];
    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" graphObject:(FBGraphObject*)params completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"done posting");
        }
    }];
 }
```

How can I make multiple posts to feed (& album), each with 1 or more photos and have them show as separate posts on the users wall?

Just looking for a general approach how to do this using Graph api, not necessarily code.

Comment: Would appreciate any help or feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `me/albums` to create new album, `ALBUM_ID/photos` to upload a photo.

Comment: I tried it and this doesn't work either. I don't want to keep creating albums for each post. If I use the same album, than behavior on the feed is same as posting to me/photos, i.e. posts are consolidated on the feed and only latest one shows at the top. Also custom album has a limit on number of photos you can store. I wonder how Instagram is doing it. You can do 2 posts one after the other and each shows up as a separate feed post.